# How can i check if data exists in multiple places in the state?

Tags: javascript

```
{
  foo: {
    'bar1': {
      id: 1,
      appeal_id: 88,
      edited: true
    },
    'bar2': {
      id: 2,
      foo_id: 88
    },
    'bar3': {
      id: 3,
      foo_id: 88
    }
  }
}
```

How can check if bar 1 or 2 or 3 have `edited:true`?

If i do something like this it works `this.props.foo.bar1.edited` works but i would like to check if any of the child elements have the edited flag. There will usually be only 1-4 so i am not worried about performance.

Comment: You can use lodash's find for this, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find

Comment: Why just not use loop and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With underscore or lodash:

```
let _ = require('underscore');  // or lodash
let state = { /* object in OP */ };
let result = _.filter(state.foo, value => value.edited);
```

Gives an array of values for which edited is truth, like:

> [ { id: 1, appeal_id: 88, edited: true } ]

Answer (score 0):

Like i say in my comment, just use a loop.

```
for (let key in object.foo) {
    if(object.foo[key]['edited']) {
       console.log('found')
    }
}
```